# Regex for exact url match excluding a particular word

Tags: regex

I am not good with regex so wanted to know if we can do an exact match with a url excluding a string in the url content.

Should match -

1. http://loadbalance.com/
2. http://us-loadbalance.com/
3. http://ch-loadbalance.com/

Should not match -

1. http://loadbalance.com/site.aspx
2. http://us-loadbalance.com/site.aspx
3. http://ch-loadbalance.com/site.aspx

So irrespective of which string its prefixed or not (us- , ch-, none) it should match. But if any part of the url is mentioned after the .com then it should not match it. Need the result in bool as true or false not extract the string from it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example strings you could use a negated character class `[^/]` which will match not a forward slash. Then after that do match the forward slash at the end and use `^` and `$` anchors to assert the beginning and the end of the line:

[`^https?://[^/]+\/$`](https://regex101.com/r/yo73Op/1/)

There is no programming language specified so the returning a boolean part is up to you.

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(http|https):\/\/[\w.-]+\/
```

If you need to add something else, You can go to a [online service](http://regex101.com) to help you create regex

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `(http:\/\/).*[(\.com\/)$]\/`
The regex matches the input until a `.com/`

This site might help to test and come up with Regex - https://regexr.com/